# How to convert the Pandas string values of a column into a column of a list of strings?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following dataset:

```
    Name     Codes
0    Tom  a1,a2,a3
1   nick  a1,b2,b3
2  krish  a1,b2,c3
3   jack  a5,c3,b1
```

How do I convert `Codes` to be a list inside my data frame column?
I need the following result:

```
    Name     Codes
0    Tom  [a1,a2,a3]
1   nick  [a1,b2,b3]
2  krish  [a1,b2,c3]
3   jack  [a5,c3,b1]
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way would be as follows:

```
df['Codes'] = df['Codes'].str.split()
```

Its usually a good idea to favor built in functions when using pandas. These will usually have very efficient implementations in cython.

A more flexible, but slower solution would be to apply an arbitrary python function -

```
df['Codes'] = df['Codes'].apply(lambda x: x.split())
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple `str.split(...)` call is sufficient

```
>>> df.Codes.str.split(",")
0    [a1, a2, a3]
1    [a1, b2, b3]
2    [a1, b2, c3]
3    [a5, c3, b1]
```